# Method to find optimal-ish result for numerous combinations

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a pool of *n* objects, and each object has a known degree of "compatibility" with each other object. Recognizing that "best" is a relative term, how can I best group these objects into *n*/2 pairs where the overall result is "good"?

To further clarify, it'd be fairly simple to just iterate over the entire batch and say, "What's the best match for this one?", put them together, and move on, but that may lead to some items at the end of the process that have very low compatibility being paired, and a small change earlier on (perhaps making a second-best match) might have increased the overall quality of matches across the entire pool.

Comment: http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html finds a maximum (or minimum) matching if you can define your compatibilty scores as weights. There's also a link to an implementation.

Comment: For background before taking @PaulHankin's excellent suggestion, first see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory). Your problem is the "General Graphs" variety with edge weights connoting compatibility.

Comment: This definitely helps me name the problem so I can look further into it--thanks! Hope I've got enough of a mathematical background to understand what I find!